# geolocation's enableHighAccuracy=false not always supported?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, geolocation, phonegap-plugins

On some devices that I have I can only get my position if enableHighAccuracy is set to 'true', not if it's set to 'false'. It doesn't time out or throws an error, just keeps on searching.

Isn't this feature always supported?

I'm using cordova and is testing on android devices right now. Have tried different location settings on my phone and nothing seems to help.

Example

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        alert(position);
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error);
    }, { 
        maximumAge: 3000, 
        timeout: 30000, 
        enableHighAccuracy: false 
    }
);
```

Comment: on android, cordova uses the webview geolocation, so the support will deppend on the android version or if the device vendor changed something on the default webview that broke the geolocation

Comment: Thanks for the awnser! It now seems to work on my device when i turned wifi on for a little while. This is so strange!